# How to create pg_trgm compound indexes with date columns

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm

```
SELECT col1, max(date) as max_date
FROM table
WHERE col1 ILIKE 'name'
GROUP BY col1
```

Here col1 is `varchar` and date is `timestamp with time zone` data type. So created extension `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm`

Then tried the following indexes and got the errors:

1: Issue: ERROR:  operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not accept data type timestamp with time zone

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY trgm_table_col1_date_index
ON table 
USING gin (provider_id, date gin_trgm_ops);
```

2: Issue: ERROR:  operator class "text_pattern_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"

```
 CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY trgm_table_col1_date_index
    ON table 
    USING gin (provider_id, date text_pattern_ops);
```

How can I create an index for the above query for faster execution? Any help will be really appreciated!

EDIT: So this works syntactically but does not speed up the query:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY trgm_provider_date_index
ON table 
USING gin (provider_id gin_trgm_ops, date_var)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Postgres is not able to optimise `min()`/`max()` queries using a GIN index.

You *can* add `date` columns to a GIN index (as well as other scalar types, like `int`, `text`, etc.) by installing the [`btree_gin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gin.html) contrib module. However, because GIN indexing methods are under no obligation to store their entries in any particular order, Postgres can't assume that they'll be useful for finding the maximum, so they'll be ignored.

(I can't find a specific reference to this in the docs, but I believe that it's identical to [the limitation which prevents anything other than a B-tree from being used to optimise an `ORDER BY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-ordering.html).)

Comment: Please check my edit. Creating index like this works but did not speed up the query. `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY trgm_general_provider_date_index
ON general_catalog 
USING gin (provider_id gin_trgm_ops, acquisition_date)`

Comment: @Atihska: Like I said, I wouldn't expect it to help, if you're comparing it to an index on `provider_id` alone (if anything, the additional column is going to make it worse).

Comment: So just create index on `provider_id`? How can I make it faster?

Comment: @Atihska: "How can I make it faster" is a bit too broad to address in comments. You should probably post a new question. Be sure to include table and index definitions, sample data, the problematic query, and your `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` output.